# Concatenation of CLOB datatypes in a LOOP in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, clob

I am trying to concatenate clobs in a PL/SQL loop and it has been returning null whilst when using DBMS_OUTPUT prints out the loop values and when executing each result of the clobs gives an output as well.

The system is meant to execute an already stored SQL in a table based on the report name passed into it. This particular report has many report names; hence the concatenation of each of the reports. The arguments passed are the report name, version of the report you're interested in, the kind of separator you want, and an argument list for the unknowns in the SQL if any. There are also two main types of SQL; 1 that needs the table_name be replaced with a temp table_name and another that needs an ID be appended to a table_name in the SQL.

please find below the code for the REPREF1 function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION REPREF1(P_VER       IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'LATEST',
                                   P_SEPARATOR IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ', ',
                                   P_ARGLIST   IN VAR DEFAULT NULL) RETURN CLOB IS
  L_CLOB CLOB;
  FUNCTION GET_CLOB(P_REPNAM    IN VARCHAR2,
                    P_VER       IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'LATEST',
                    P_SEPARATOR IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ', ',
                    P_ARGLIST   IN VAR DEFAULT NULL) RETURN CLOB IS
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- TITLE - GET_CLOB beta - b.0  DATE 2010Mar12
    --
    -- DESCRIPTION -  A function that return a report based on the report name put in
    --
    -- USAGE - select get_clob(p_repnam,p_ver, p_separator, var(varay(val_1,...val_n), varay(val_1,...val_n))) FROM dual
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    V_SQL       VARCHAR2(32767);
    L_RESULT    CLOB;
    V_TITLE     VARCHAR2(4000);
    V_REPDATE   VARCHAR2(30);
    V_CNT       NUMBER(2);
    V_NUMARG    NUMBER(3);
    V_CDCRU     NUMBER(3);
    V_BCNT      NUMBER(3);
    V_NEWTABDAT VARCHAR2(30);
    V_NEWTABLIN VARCHAR2(30);
    L_COLLIST   VARAY;
    V_VER       VARCHAR2(6);
    N           PLS_INTEGER;
    V_CNTTAB    NUMBER(3);

    -- EXEC_SQL_CLOB  
    FUNCTION EXEC_SQL_CLOB(P_SQL       IN VARCHAR2,
                           P_NUMARG    IN NUMBER,
                           P_COLLIST   IN VARAY DEFAULT NULL,
                           P_ARGLIST   IN VARAY DEFAULT NULL,
                           P_SEPARATOR IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '') RETURN CLOB IS
      ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- TITLE - EXEC_SQL_CLOB beta - b.0  DATE 2010Mar22
      --
      -- DESCRIPTION -  A function that returns a clob value after executing the sql query that is passed into it 
      --
      -- USAGE - select exec_sql_clob(p_sql, p_numarg, var(varay(val_1, val_2,...val_n), varay(val_1, val_2,...val_n))) FROM dual
      ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      L_CUR       INTEGER DEFAULT DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
      L_STATUS    INTEGER;
      V_COL       VARCHAR2(4000);
      L_RESULT    CLOB;
      L_COLCNT    NUMBER DEFAULT 0;
      L_SEPARATOR VARCHAR2(10) DEFAULT '';
      V_NUMARG    NUMBER(3);

    BEGIN
      -- parse the query for the report
      DBMS_SQL.PARSE(L_CUR, P_SQL, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
      -- whilst it is not more than 255 per line
      FOR I IN 1 .. 255
      LOOP
        BEGIN
          -- define each column in the select list
          DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(L_CUR, I, V_COL, 2000);
          L_COLCNT := I;
        EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            IF (SQLCODE = -1007) THEN
              EXIT;
            ELSE
              RAISE;
            END IF;
        END;
      END LOOP;

      -- If query has no bind variables
      IF (P_ARGLIST IS NULL) THEN
        IF (P_NUMARG = 0) THEN
          -- Execute the query in the cursor
          L_STATUS := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(L_CUR);
          LOOP
            -- Exit loop when fetch is complete
            EXIT WHEN(DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(L_CUR) <= 0);
            L_SEPARATOR := '';
            FOR I IN 1 .. L_COLCNT
            LOOP
              DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(L_CUR, I, V_COL);
              L_RESULT    := L_RESULT || L_SEPARATOR || V_COL;
              L_RESULT    := REPLACE(REPLACE(L_RESULT, CHR(13) || CHR(10), ' '), CHR(10), ' ');
              L_SEPARATOR := P_SEPARATOR;
            END LOOP;
            L_RESULT := L_RESULT || CHR(13);
          END LOOP;
        ELSE
          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20011, ' INCORRECT NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS PASSED IN LIST ');
        END IF;
        -- Query has bind variables
      ELSE
        -- Check if the numarg passed is the same has stored in the table
        SELECT NUMARG
          INTO V_NUMARG
          FROM REPVER
         WHERE REPCODE = P_SQL;
        -- If number of arguments is greater than 0
        IF (V_NUMARG > 0) THEN
          -- Check if the number of arguments are the same
          IF (P_NUMARG = V_NUMARG) THEN
            -- Replace the bind variables in the query
            FOR J IN 1 .. P_ARGLIST.COUNT
            LOOP
              DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(L_CUR, P_COLLIST(J), P_ARGLIST(J));
            END LOOP;
            -- Execute the query in the cursor
            L_STATUS := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(L_CUR);
            LOOP
              -- Exit loop when fetch is complete
              EXIT WHEN(DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(L_CUR) <= 0);
              L_SEPARATOR := '';
              FOR I IN 1 .. L_COLCNT
              LOOP
                DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(L_CUR, I, V_COL);
                L_RESULT    := L_RESULT || L_SEPARATOR || V_COL;
                L_RESULT    := REPLACE(REPLACE(L_RESULT, CHR(13) || CHR(10), ' '), CHR(10), ' ');
                L_SEPARATOR := P_SEPARATOR;
              END LOOP;
              L_RESULT := L_RESULT || CHR(13);
            END LOOP;
          ELSE
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20011, ' INCORRECT NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS PASSED IN LIST ');
          END IF;
        ELSE
          -- If the number of argument is equal to 0
          IF (P_NUMARG = 0) THEN
            -- Execute the query in the cursor
            L_STATUS := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(L_CUR);
            LOOP
              -- Exit loop when fetch is complete
              EXIT WHEN(DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(L_CUR) <= 0);
              L_SEPARATOR := '';
              FOR I IN 1 .. L_COLCNT
              LOOP
                DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(L_CUR, I, V_COL);
                L_RESULT    := L_RESULT || L_SEPARATOR || V_COL;
                L_RESULT    := REPLACE(REPLACE(L_RESULT, CHR(13) || CHR(10), ' '), CHR(10), ' ');
                L_SEPARATOR := P_SEPARATOR;
              END LOOP;
              L_RESULT := L_RESULT || CHR(13);
            END LOOP;
          ELSE
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20011, ' INCORRECT NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS PASSED IN LIST ');
          END IF;
        END IF;
      END IF;
      -- Close cursor
      DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(L_CUR);
      RETURN L_RESULT;
    END EXEC_SQL_CLOB;
  BEGIN
    -- Check if the version entered is null or latest
    IF (P_VER IS NULL)
       OR (UPPER(P_VER) = UPPER('LATEST')) THEN
      SELECT MAX(VER)
        INTO V_VER
        FROM REPORT B, REPVER R
       WHERE UPPER(REPNAM) = UPPER(P_REPNAM)
         AND B.REPREF = R.REPREF;
    ELSE
      V_VER := P_VER;
    END IF;

    -- Check if the repname and version entered exists
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO V_CNT
      FROM REPORT B, REPVER R
     WHERE UPPER(REPNAM) = UPPER(P_REPNAM)
       AND VER = V_VER
       AND B.REPREF = R.REPREF;

    IF (V_CNT > 0) THEN
      -- Store the SQL statement, title and number of arguments of the report name passed.
      SELECT REPCODE, REPTITLE, NUMARG, COLLIST
        INTO V_SQL, V_TITLE, V_NUMARG, L_COLLIST
        FROM REPVER R, REPORT B
       WHERE UPPER(REPNAM) = UPPER(P_REPNAM)
         AND B.REPREF = R.REPREF
         AND VER = V_VER;

      V_REPDATE := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI');

      L_RESULT := V_TITLE || ' (' || P_REPNAM || ' version ' || V_VER || ') generated ' || V_REPDATE || CHR(13) || CHR(13);

      -- Check for some specific type of queries
      SELECT COUNT(*)
        INTO V_CDCRU
        FROM REPVER R, REPORT B
       WHERE CTDDATA = 'Y'
         AND UPPER(REPNAM) = UPPER(P_REPNAM)
         AND B.REPREF = R.REPREF
         AND VER = V_VER;

      SELECT COUNT(*)
        INTO V_BCNT
        FROM REPVER R, BODCREPS B
       WHERE BENLIST = 'Y'
         AND UPPER(REPNAM) = UPPER(P_REPNAM)
         AND B.REPREF = R.REPREF
         AND VER = V_VER;

      IF (V_CDCRU > 0) THEN

        V_NEWTABDATA := 'CT_' || 'DAT_' || P_ARGLIST(1) (P_ARGLIST(1).FIRST);
        V_NEWTABLINK := 'CT_' || 'LIN_' || P_ARGLIST(1) (P_ARGLIST(1).FIRST);

        -- Check if the tables exist
        SELECT COUNT(*)
          INTO V_CNTTAB
          FROM ALL_TABLES
         WHERE TABLE_NAME = V_NEWTABDAT
            OR TABLE_NAME = V_NEWTABLIN
           AND OWNER = 'SCOTT';

        IF (V_CNTTAB > 0) THEN

          V_SQL := UPPER(V_SQL);
          V_SQL := REPLACE(V_SQL, 'CT_DAT_CRU', V_NEWTABDAT);
          V_SQL := REPLACE(V_SQL, 'CT_LIN_CRU', V_NEWTABLIN);

        ELSE
          V_SQL := 'SELECT ''THE TABLE NOT CREATED YET''
                              FROM DUAL';
        END IF;
      END IF;

      IF (V_BCNT > 0) THEN

        V_SQL := UPPER(V_SQL);
        V_SQL := REPLACE(V_SQL, 'LIST', P_ARGLIST(1) (P_ARGLIST(1).LAST));

      END IF;

      IF (P_ARGLIST IS NULL) THEN
        -- execute the query
        L_RESULT := L_RESULT || EXEC_SQL_CLOB(V_SQL, V_NUMARG, L_COLLIST, NULL, P_SEPARATOR);
      ELSE
        N := P_ARGLIST.COUNT;
        -- execute the query
        L_RESULT := L_RESULT || EXEC_SQL_CLOB(V_SQL, V_NUMARG, L_COLLIST, P_ARGLIST(N), P_SEPARATOR);
      END IF;
      RETURN L_RESULT;
    ELSE
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20012, P_REPNAM || ' or ' || P_VER || ' DOES NOT EXIST ');
    END IF;
  END GET_CLOB;
BEGIN
  FOR I IN (SELECT REPNAM
              FROM REPORT
             WHERE REPREF NOT IN ('R01', 'R02', 'R03', 'R04'))
  LOOP
    SELECT CONCAT_CLOB(GET_CLOB(I.REPNAM, P_VER, P_SEPARATOR, P_ARGLIST))
      INTO L_CLOB
      FROM DUAL;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I.REPNAM);
    -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (COUNT(i.REPNAM));
  END LOOP;
  RETURN L_CLOB;
END REPREF1;

/
```

Cheers,
Tunde

Many thanks APC for making the code look better.
@Robert, the last loop in the code returns null even with the CONCAT_CLOB aggregate function that concatenates clobs.

```
FOR I IN (SELECT REPNAM
            FROM REPORT
           WHERE REPREF NOT IN ('R01', 'R02', 'R03', 'R04'))
LOOP
  SELECT CONCAT_CLOB(GET_CLOB(I.REPNAM, P_VER, P_SEPARATOR, P_ARGLIST))
    INTO L_CLOB
    FROM DUAL;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I.REPNAM);
END LOOP;
```

when I try this,

```
FOR I IN (SELECT REPNAM
            FROM REPORT
           WHERE REPREF NOT IN ('R01', 'R02', 'R03', 'R04'))
LOOP
  L_CLOB := L_CLOB || CHR(13) || GET_CLOB(I.REPNAM, P_VER, P_SEPARATOR, P_ARGLIST);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I.REPNAM);
END LOOP;
```

It also gives null; but this time the dbms output for the repnam are not complete.

Comment: Nothing we like better than sifting through several hundred lines of someone else's shonky code.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about your code. Here is how it works for me:
Whenever I create a function returning a clob value I do this:

```
function foo return clob is
l_clob clob;
begin
      dbms_lob.createtemporary(lob_loc => l_clob, cache => true, dur => dbms_lob.call);
      ...
      return l_clob;
end;
```

When concatenating values into a clob I use a function:

```
   procedure add_string_to_clob(p_lob    in out nocopy clob
                             ,p_string varchar2) is
   begin
      dbms_lob.writeappend(lob_loc => p_lob, amount => length(p_string), buffer => p_string);
   end;
```

Comment: Rene, quick question about this line: `dbms_lob.createtemporary(lob_loc => l_lob, cache => true, dur => dbms_lob.call);` Is that `lob_loc => l_lob` supposed to be `lob_loc => l_clob` ?

Comment: @JWiley yup, typo fixed

Comment: Glad that got fixed after 9 years !

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

`dbms_lob.substr(your clob parameter,start position, length)`

e.g

`dbms_output('my clob value:' || dbms_lob.substr(your clob parameter,start position, length);`

But you can print in a string max 4000 character, you can then use this in a looping function to print 4000 characters in each line.